# Is there a way to stop cp from overwriting the second of two globbed files

Tags: bash, cp

Intention:
`cp /path/to/code.{c,h} .`

Concise version:
`cp /path/to/code.* .`

Re-occurring typo:
`cp /path/to/code.*`

In the typo case the second file is overwritten by the first.
This has bitten me repeatedly and I'm not optimistic there's a solution outside of re-writing my neural circuits, but one can dream.

Asking for confirmation every time or some visual indication of danger would both be solutions.

Defaulting to --no-clobber or some such is not a solution because I am usually clobbering something in the intended destination.

Comment: How about `-i`?

Comment: You could set an alias for always using -i

Comment: If the files are important and textual, you should version control them with [git](https://git-scm.com/) - or some other tool

Answer (score 1):

As suggested, you could create an alias

```
alias cp='cp -i'
```

such that you will always be prompted when invoking cp from the command line. Note that this will not affect scripts.

The man page for cp has this to say:

```
   -i, --interactive
          prompt before overwrite (overrides a previous -n option)
```